# += symbol's difference in string and textbox

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

Sorry for asking this silly question. I have a `string msg+="hi";` and a button to print that message  using label.

No matter how many time I pressed the button the label display "hi" only one time.

Another thing is i have a `label1.text += textbox.text;` if click the button it display the message entered by user many time based on the number of clicks.

Can someone explain me what is difference storing a message in string then display it using label and straight away display t using label.

```
string msg += "hi";
label1.text = msg;

output: hi
//button clicked many times but only one output

label1.text += textbox.text;
//that I input = hi!
//button I clicked 4 times
output = hi! hi! hi! hi!
```

Comment: Share the code please.

Comment: You use = the first time, use +=.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press button and you call method that use

> string msg += "hi";

you actually still make new instance of msg and insert "hi".

But when you press button and you have in textbox string "hi" and you call method that use

> label1.text += textbox.text;

you don't instantiate something, you just insert "hi" after string that is in label1.text.

It is because msg is local variable and label1.text is global variable (that's why you don't instantiate it all the time).

Answer (score 2):

In actual scenario `string msg += "hi";`  will give compile time error.
lets consider this:

```
string msg = string.Empty;
        msg = "hi";
        Label.Text += msg;
```

this will also depend on the control view state, if it set to false no matter the number of click 'Hi' will be shown only once.
by default view state of control is set to true.
Same goes for text box control too.